# Device not in nanoff --listdevices result

Tags: esp32, nanoframework

My device from "Freenove Super Starter Kit for ESP32-S3" is not found in the list of devices

1. I execute

```
nanoff --target ESP32_S3_BLE --serialport COM5 --update --reset --masserase
```

2. I get this result :

```
.NET nanoFramework Firmware Flasher v2.5.59+e3ff02e768
Copyright (C) 2019 .NET Foundation and nanoFramework project contributors

Reading details from chip...OK

Connected to:
ESP32-S3 (ESP32-S3 (revision v0.1))
Features WiFi, BLE
Flash size 8MB GD25Q64 from GIGADEVICE (manufacturer 0x200 device 0x16407)
PSRAM: undetermined
Crystal 40MHz
MAC 34:85:18:6D:35:40

Extracting ESP32_S3_BLE-1.9.1.21.zip...OK

Updating to 1.9.1.21

Erasing flash...OK
Flashing firmware...OK
```

3. I execute :

```
nanoff --listdevices
```

4. I get this result :

```
.NET nanoFramework Firmware Flasher v2.5.59+e3ff02e768
Copyright (C) 2019 .NET Foundation and nanoFramework project contributors

No devices found
```

I expect that the device is in the list
(I suppose it is why the device do no appear in the devices list in Visual Studio)

I try to flash many times the device with different targets with the same bad result

I use :

- Visual Studio : 2022
- .NET nanoFramework Extension : 2022.3.0.73
- target name : ESP32_S3_BLE
- firmware version : 1.9.1.21
- nanooff : 2.5.59

Comment: You have to press the reset button after flashing it in order to get the new firmware running.

Comment: Hey @regis1512, this question has been asked on the project's GitHub [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/1453).

Comment: It is good for me.
Thanks.